# npm cant install dependencies for my project err 404 on logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a polished browser game from Github as I was trying out games made with HTML5 and javascript.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest) to the game's Github.

---

**This was on the npm debug**
 237 error 404 Not Found
237 error 404
237 error 404 'websocket-server' is not in the npm registry.
237 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it
237 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'BrowserQuest'
237 error 404
237 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
237 error 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
238 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
239 error command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-d"
240 error cwd D:\Web\hellophaser\BrowserQuest-master
241 error node -v v0.10.33
242 error npm -v 1.4.28
243 error code E404

---

as for my package.json

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "BrowserQuest"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": false 
  , "dependencies": {
    "underscore": ">0"
    , "log": ">0"
    , "bison": ">0"
    , "websocket": ">0"
    , "websocket-server": ">0"
    , "sanitizer": ">0"
    , "memcache": ">0"
  }
}
```

---

Im guessing that the problem is with the **underscore** module. How do I download it manually? and how do I add it to my project?

Comment: Mmh, I'd say the problem is `websocket-server`: *"237 error 404 'websocket-server' is not in the npm registry."*. It was unpublished: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-server. Solution: Use a package that exists.

Comment: Hey! actually i tried installing underscore alone and i get a **no repository field** error. anyways thanks for the answer. Ill update my question as I am getting different errors everytime i punch in npm install -d in my project directory.

Comment: That's probably a warning, not an error (the install should still work fine)
, and refers to *your* package, which indeed doesn't have a repository field. But even if it refers to the underscore package, that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `packages.json` file is outdated, since the package `websocket-server` has been unpublished. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-server.

I would recommend to file an issue on the original repo, but they have the issue tracker disabled.

[image]

Comment: This saves me the hassle then. thanks! are there any similar or alternative modules to this?

Comment: @Gokigooooks `node-websocket-server` is still in npm, written (though not published) by the same guy, and is a fork of `websocket-server` - that might work. Though the GitHub repo warns that it is deprecated, so use with caution.

Comment: @Gokigooooks Yeah, test @Timespace suggestion, it really might work. Just change the `websocket-server` string in the `package.json` file to `node-websocket-server` and rerun `rnpm install`